# XML get element with xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

Ive got this xml:

```
<root>
    <provision>
        <Stage StageNumber="1"/>
        <Stage StageNumber="2"/>
    </provision>
    <provision>
        <Stage StageNumber="1"/>
        <Stage StageNumber="2"/>
    </provision>
    <provision>
        <Stage StageNumber="1"/>
        <Stage StageNumber="3"/>
    </provision>
    <Stage StageNumber="1"/>
    <Stage StageNumber="2"/>
    <Stage StageNumber="3"/>
</root>
```

and i need to select attribute `StageNumber` that has single `provision` on it; 
By single i mean that i have 3 stages, and every `stage` got some `provision` in it, but data stored in different way.
It that case answer should be `3`.

Comment: Can you explain "_that has single `provision` on it_" more? It isn't clear why the answer should be `3`. I don't see the difference between any of the `provision` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound as you like to find  a Stage with unique StageNumber. 
Try this;

```
.//Stage[ not(
        ../preceding-sibling::provision/Stage/@StageNumber = @StageNumber  or 
        ../following-sibling::provision/Stage/@StageNumber = @StageNumber)]"
```